# Load Partial View based on Autocomplete Selection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, partial-views, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm just learning ASP.NET, MVC, and JScript for the first time. I'm attempting to use the selection from an autocomplete to do an ajax call get data and load a partial view with that data. The controller gets the request with the selected Id, but the partial view never loads. What am I doing wrong?

(the view and partial view have different models - I didn't think that would be an issue)

**CONTROLLER**

```
    public ActionResult GetEmployee(int id)
    {
        HumanResourcesManager man = new HumanResourcesManager();
        var emp = man.GetEmployee(id);
        return PartialView("_EmployeeDetails", emp);
    }
```

**VIEW**

```
@model HumanResources.Web.Models.EmployeeModel
<p>
      Selected Employee: @Html.TextBox("EmployeeSearch")
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#EmployeeSearch").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                url: "@(Url.Action("FindEmployee", "Employee"))",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { term: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return { label: item.DisplayName, value: item.DisplayName, id: item.Id };
                        }))
                    }
                })
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            if (ui.item) {
                GetEmployeeDetails(ui.item.id);
            }
        }
    });


    function GetEmployeeDetails(id) {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Employee/GetEmployee',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        data: { id: id },
        success: function (result) {
            $("#partialView").html(result);
        }
    });
    }

    </script>

    <div id="#partialView">
        @*Partial View Test*@
    </div>
```

**PARTIAL VIEW**

```
@model HumanResources.Objects.Employee.EmployeeInformation
@{ 
    Layout = null;
}

<h1>THIS IS A TEST</h1>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `#` from your partial view div id. You only add it when you're using jQuery's [id selector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

```
<div id="partialView">
    @*Partial View Test*@
</div>
```